# can not update the actual quantity value in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to update the quantity in the index method. but the index view's input submit button cannot work for that data can not bind. still, quantity no update and I show the value of quantity which I already used. but I want to update this.

Here Is My Code

```
namespace Amazon.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class ShopController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private IHostingEnvironment _he;

        public ShopController(ApplicationDbContext db, IHostingEnvironment he) //input parameter
        {
            _db = db;
            _he = he;
        }


       
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_db.Shop.Include(c => c.Category).Include(f => f.SubCategory).ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Shop shop)
        {
            _db.Shop.Update(shop);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

```
    @using Amazon.Models
    @model IEnumerable<Shop>
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    }
    
    <br /><br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-info">Product List</h2>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-info">&nbsp;Add New Product </a>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped border" id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table-info">
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Name)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Price)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.PreviousPrice)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Quantity)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Description)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Size)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.CategoryTypeId)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.SubCategoryTypeId)
                        </th>
    
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr class="text-info">
    
                            <td>  @item.Name </td>
                            <td>  @item.Price </td>
                            <td>  @item.PreviousPrice </td>
                            @*<td>@item.Quantity</td>*@
    
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="submit" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
                                    <input type="submit" step="1" max="" value="@item.Quantity"  name="quantity" asp-for="@item.Quantity" class="quantity-field">
                                    <input type="submit" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>  @item.Description </td>
                            <td>  @item.Size </td>
                            <td>  @item.Category.CategoryName </td>
                            <td>  @item.SubCategory.SubCategoryName </td>
                            <td>
                                <partial name="_DeletePartial" model="@item.Id" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br /> <br />
    
    @section scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myTable').DataTable();
            });
        </script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function incrementValue(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
                var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
                var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);
    
                if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                    parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
                } else {
                    parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
                }
            }
    
            function decrementValue(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
                var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
                var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);
    
                if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                    parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
                } else {
                    parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
                }
            }
    
            $('.input-group').on('click', '.button-plus', function (e) {
                incrementValue(e);
            });
    
            $('.input-group').on('click', '.button-minus', function (e) {
                decrementValue(e);
            });
        </script>
    }
```

my output is

[image]

when I update quantity these using spinner then it does not update the actual value of the quantity.
I am beginner, please help anyone.

Comment: What do you mean by "not update the actual value"? Do you want to put this in database? Where is the code to update the database record? How are you calling `public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Shop shop)` method?

Comment: not update the actual value means when I click plus/minus button then value similarly increase and decrease.but can not update database of quantity.and when I upload new shop product, then I was already set there the value of quantity.but the index method, here I try to again update my quantity for easily decrease and increase quantity into the database

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the value changed by your click on the button to the database, I think you can do so.

View.cshtml:

```
<div class="input-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
                        <input type="submit" step="1" max="" value="@item.Quantity" name="quantity" asp-for="@item.Quantity"class="quantity-field">
                        <input type="submit" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
                        <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@item.Id" data-field="quantity"/>
                    </div>
```

js in view:

```
 $('.input-group').on('click', '.button-plus', function (e) {
            incrementValue(e);
            var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
            var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
            var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);
            var id = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=Id ]').val());
            $.ajax({ url: 'blogs/test', type: 'get', data: { "value": currentVal ,"id":id}, dataType: 'json', success: function (data) { console.log(data) } })
        });

        $('.input-group').on('click', '.button-minus', function (e) {
            decrementValue(e);
            var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
            var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
            var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);
            var id = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=Id ]').val());
            $.ajax({ url: 'blogs/test', type: 'get', data: { "value": currentVal, "id": id}, dataType: 'json', success: function (data) { console.log(data) } })
        });
```

controller:

```
public IActionResult  Test(int id,int value)
        {
            var blog=_context.Blogs.Find(id);
            blog.Quantity = value;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Json("ok");
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
           return View(await _context.Blogs.ToListAsync());
        }
```

result:
[image]